# RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working smoothly if use picasso

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. Scrolling is working but it's not working smoothly when I use picasso. Can someone point me to get smoothly.

**MainActivity.java**

```
recycler_view_ways = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ways);    
recycler_view_ways.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));    
recycler_view_ways.setHasFixedSize(true);    
recycler_view_ways.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGray">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_ways"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

             <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_type"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>        

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RVAdapter**

```
/*if (type.getPhotos() != null && type.getPhotos().size() > 0) {
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://cap.com/uploads/photos/" + type.getPhotos().get(0).getPhoto()).into(holder.img);
}*/
```

Comment: Try to use picasso method resize(width,height) after load() it will reduce picture size hope that can help u

Comment: @Lokesh Desai I don't want to resize. Do u know other ways working with image loading in android? Thank You,

Comment: can u please try Glide library ..